# Magento Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'bn_magento'@'localhost'

Tags: xampp, beta, magento2

```
a:4:{i:0;s:92:
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'bn_magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)";i:1;s:5974:"
#0 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(328): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(460): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect()
#3 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8;', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(433): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8;', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(488): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SET NAMES utf8;', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Type\Db\Pdo\Mysql.php(63): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8;')
#7 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Type\Db\ConnectionFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Type\Db\Pdo\Mysql->getConnection(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\Null))
#8 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Resource\ConnectionFactory.php(24): Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Type\Db\ConnectionFactory->create(Array)
#9 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Resource.php(113): Magento\Framework\App\Resource\ConnectionFactory->create(Array)
#10 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Resource.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\Resource->getConnectionByName('default')
#11 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb.php(305): Magento\Framework\App\Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#12 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb.php(335): Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb->_getConnection('write')
#13 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb.php(320): Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb->_getWriteAdapter()
#14 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb.php(345): Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb->_getReadAdapter()
#15 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\var\generation\Magento\Store\Model\Resource\Website\Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb->getReadConnection()
#16 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection.php(123): Magento\Store\Model\Resource\Website\Interceptor->getReadConnection()
#17 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(107): Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Cache), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), NULL, NULL)
#18 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(91): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Store\\M...', Array)
#19 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Store\\M...', Array)
#20 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\var\generation\Magento\Store\Model\Resource\Website\CollectionFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\Store\\...', Array)
#21 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\Magento\Store\Model\Storage\Db.php(198): Magento\Store\Model\Resource\Website\CollectionFactory->create()
#22 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\Magento\Store\Model\Storage\Db.php(468): Magento\Store\Model\Storage\Db->_initStores()
#23 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\Magento\Store\Model\StorageFactory.php(142): Magento\Store\Model\Storage\Db->reinitStores()
#24 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\Magento\Store\Model\StorageFactory.php(117): Magento\Store\Model\StorageFactory->_reinitStores(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Storage\Db), Array)
#25 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager.php(121): Magento\Store\Model\StorageFactory->get(Array)
#26 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager.php(187): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->_getStorage()
#27 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\Magento\Store\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor.php(35): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStores(false, true)
#28 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\var\generation\Magento\Store\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Store\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/')
#29 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http.php(146): Magento\Store\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/')
#30 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->setPathInfo()
#31 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http.php(189): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->getPathInfo()
#32 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Http.php(110): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getFrontName()
#33 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#34 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#35 {main}
";s:3:"url";s:9:"/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";}
```

Comment: What process does threw this error for you, are you trying to setup magento2 ?

Comment: it seems your user doesnt have permission to the db. check db permissions for localhost user.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this error occurred due to the change of the password in cPanel.
So I edited the local.xml file, changed the password to the correct one, and everything was back to normal.

Thanks to everyone that contributed.